# Query on java singleton pattern

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, singleton

I have some conceptual idea on singleton pattern , i am confused on how singleton work in different classloaders .
I have tried to find out this but could not get the exact idea.
Singleton objects are basically single instance per class loader. 
In the case of distributed applications, where i have more than one application deployed on my server and i have created a singleton object in one application , when i am trying to access this singleton object from another application since the classloader is different it will create a new instance .
how to control it??

Comment: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) has some good info on that pattern and it's in java

Answer (score 0):

> In the case of distributed applications, where i have more than one
>   application deployed on my server and i have created a singleton
>   object in one application , when i am trying to access this singleton
>   object from another application since the classloader is different it
>   will create a new instance

Multiple classloaders on multiple JVMs will cause singleton pattern to break as you will have several instances of that class.

Probably the best use for a singleton in an clustered app server is when the singleton is totally state-less(These are created while the ApplicationContext is being initialized. The same instance will be returned/injected during the lifetime of this ApplicationContext.), and is only used as a convenience to access global data/functions.

Answer (score 0):

Different applications on the server should not interfere with each other. This is why server creates different class loaders for them. They behave as if they are running on different JVMs.

Comment: In an environment with a single JVM but multiple classloaders, my understanding is that more than 1 class object can be created from the same fully-qualified class name and therefore it is still possible to create more than 1 instance of the class (i am referring to class declaration here, not class object) for both approaches.